# Tags for content type and search by this tags

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, search

i created a vocabulary called "Tags" and then a field on my content type using this vocabulary. I can create my content and add the tags, but then i search for the tags that im using and i get no results on the search. Somebody can help me? Thanks!
Drupal 7.44

Comment: What do you mean 'search' for the tags? Core search?

Comment: I mean searching on the site, i dont know what you mean by core search

Comment: Did you run cron? In admin/config/search/settings, you can see how many percent of your info has been indexed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the Term Search [module](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_search)

Comment: I installed it and make the content type search index with the tag field having some weight but the search still give me no results at all, do i have to set up some configurations? Thanks!